# Javascript combining two objects into new object with unique data element i.e. year

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following two objects in JS where `year` is unique in both objects. I want to combine them into a new object where the `year` is same.

```
var financials = [{"year": 2013, "rev_prod1": 10000, "rev_prod2": 5000}, {"year": 2014, "rev_prod1": 8000, "rev_prod2": 10000}, {"year": 2015, "rev_prod1": 15000, "rev_prod2": 20000}]

var stats = [{"year": 2013, "units_sold": 900, "hours": 55},{"year": 2014, "units_sold": 800, "hours": 45}, {"year": 2015, "units_sold": 1000, "hours": 70}]
```

The expected output will look like this:

```
var combinedData = [{"year": 2013, "rev_prod1": 10000, "rev_prod2": 5000, "units_sold": 900, "hours": 55}, {"year": 2014, "rev_prod1": 8000, "rev_prod2": 10000, "units_sold": 800, "hours": 45}, {"year": 2015, "rev_prod1": 15000, "rev_prod2": 20000, "units_sold": 1000, "hours": 70}]
```

Comment: Do you really have an object with duplicate key? `"rev_prod1": 10000, "rev_prod1": 5000` Also, what have you tried?

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: @NelsonYeung Typo on my wide, fixed it now. Thx

Comment: I think you should check lodash merge. It might help you : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the `stats` objects and merge the values by iterating the keys.

```js
var financials = [{ "year": 2013, "rev_prod1": 10000, "rev_prod2": 5000 }, { "year": 2014, "rev_prod1": 8000, "rev_prod2": 10000 }, { "year": 2015, "rev_prod1": 15000, "rev_prod2": 20000 }],
    stats = [{ "year": 2013, "units_sold": 900, "hours": 55 }, { "year": 2014, "units_sold": 800, "hours": 45 }, { "year": 2015, "units_sold": 1000, "hours": 70 }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

stats.forEach(function (o) {
    hash[o.year] = o;
});

financials.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(hash[o.year]).forEach(function (k) {
        o[k] = hash[o.year][k];
    });
});

console.log(financials);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var financials = [{ "year": 2013, "rev_prod1": 10000, "rev_prod2": 5000 }, { "year": 2014, "rev_prod1": 8000, "rev_prod2": 10000 }, { "year": 2015, "rev_prod1": 15000, "rev_prod2": 20000 }],
    stats = [{ "year": 2013, "units_sold": 900, "hours": 55 }, { "year": 2014, "units_sold": 800, "hours": 45 }, { "year": 2015, "units_sold": 1000, "hours": 70 }],
    map = new Map(stats.map(o => [o.year, o]));

financials.forEach(o => Object.assign(o, map.get(o.year)));

console.log(financials);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is just stroke of a genius. I'm learning programming on my own by building some project instead of reading books. How should I learn the kind of concepts u have just explained preferably ES6? Any book recommendation?

Comment: @Hannan, sorry, no books, but you can read some questions and answers here on SO, which have some very good ideas to solve some problems. always a good idea is to read the specs and and the examples, like on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a `hashtable` by merging similar objects using `#forEach()` and then *extract* the required array using a `#map()` function - see demo below:

```js
var financials = [{"year": 2013, "rev_prod1": 10000, "rev_prod2": 5000}, {"year": 2014, "rev_prod1": 8000, "rev_prod2": 10000}, {"year": 2015, "rev_prod1": 15000, "rev_prod2": 20000}];
var stats = [{"year": 2013, "units_sold": 900, "hours": 55},{"year": 2014, "units_sold": 800, "hours": 45}, {"year": 2015, "units_sold": 1000, "hours": 70}]
var hash = {};

// function to create a hashtable
function classify(e) {
   if(hash[e.year]) {
     Object.keys(e).forEach(function(c){
        hash[e.year][c] = e[c];
     });
   } else {
     hash[e.year] = e;
   }
}

// add to hash
financials.forEach(classify);
stats.forEach(classify);

// extract the result
var result = Object.keys(hash).map(function(e){
  return hash[e];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a function to grouping 2 list with common property, is that what you want?

```
function commonProps(list1, list2, common) {
    var output = [], commons = {}, combined = list1.concat(list2)
    for(var i in combined){
        var item = combined[i], $index
        if(commons[item[common]] != null){
            $index = commons[item[common]]
            for(var j in item){
                output[$index][j] = item[j]
            }
        } else {
            commons[item[common]] = output.push(item) -1
        }
    }

    return output
}
```